# How can I apply a depth test to vertices (not fragments)?

Tags: opengl, webgl

**TL;DR** I'm computing a depth map in a fragment shader and then trying to use that map in a vertex shader to see if vertices are 'in view' or not and the vertices don't line up with the fragment texel coordinates.  The imprecision causes rendering artifacts, and I'm seeking alternatives for filtering vertices based on depth.

**Background**. I am very loosely attempting to implement a scheme outlined in this paper (http://dash.harvard.edu/handle/1/4138746).  The idea is to represent arbitrary virtual objects as lots of tangent discs.  While they wanted to replace triangles in some graphics card of the future, I'm implementing this on conventional cards; my discs are just fans of triangles ("Discs") around center points ("Points").

This is targeting WebGL.

The strategy I intend to use, similar to what's done in the paper, is:

1. Render the Discs in a Depth-Only pass.
2. In a second (or more) pass, compute what's visible based solely on which Points are "visible" - ie their depth is <= the depth from the Depth-Only pass at that x and y.

I believe the authors of the paper used a gaussian blur on top of the equivalent of a GL_POINTS render applied to the Points (ie re-using the depth buffer from the DepthOnly pass, not clearing it) to actually render their object.  It's hard to say: the process is unfortunately a one line comment, and I'm unsure of how to duplicate it in WebGL anyway (a naive gaussian blur will just blur in the background pixels that weren't touched by the GL_POINTS call).

Instead, I'm hoping to do something slightly different, by rerendering the discs in a second pass instead as cones (center of disc becomes apex of cone, think "close the umbrella") and effectively computing a voronoi diagram on the surface of the object (ala redbook http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name19).  The idea is that an output pixel is the color value of the first disc to reach it when growing radiuses from 0 -> their natural size.

The crux of the problem is that only discs whose centers pass the depth test in the first pass should be allowed to carry on (as cones) to the 2nd pass.  Because what's true at the disc center applies to the whole disc/cone, **I believe this requires evaluating a depth test at a vertex or object level, and not at a fragment level.**

Since WebGL support for accessing depth buffers is still poor, in my first pass I am packing depth info into an RGBA Framebuffer in a fragment shader.  I then intended to use this in the vertex shader of the second pass via a sampler2D; any disc center that was closer than the relative texture2D() lookup would be allowed on to the second pass; otherwise I would hack "discarding" the vertex (its alpha would be set to 0 or some flag set that would cause discard of fragments associated with the disc/cone or etc).

This actually kind of worked but it caused horrendous z-fighting between discs that were close together (very small perturbations wildly changed which discs were visible).  I believe there is some floating point error between depth->rgba->depth.  More importantly, though, the depth texture is being set by fragment texel coords, but I'm looking up vertices, which almost certainly don't line up exactly on top of relevant texel coordinates; so I get depth +/- noise, essentially, and the noise is the issue.  Adding or subtracting .000001 or something isn't sufficient: you trade Type I errors for Type II.  My render became more accurate when I switched from NEAREST to LINEAR for the depth texture interpolation, but it still wasn't good enough.

How else can I determine which disc's centers would be visible in a given render, so that I can do a second vertex/fragment (or more) pass focused on objects associated with those points?  Or: is there a better way to go about this in general?

Comment: I think what you probably need is a geometry shader.

Comment: It's theoretically possible. You can clip vertices programatically by setting the homogenous coordinate (`w`) to **0.0** (they will project to infinity and be clipped), but for clipping individual vertices that way to work correctly about the only primitive type you can use is `GL_POINTS`. Otherwise, this is something that belongs in a geometry shader.

Comment: The question is dealing with knowing when to clip, not how to clip.  I'm already successfully hacking my way into clipping vertices in the vertex/frag shader (since I don't think WebGL supports geo shaders yet?).  I can set the vertices on edge of my discs to alpha 0.0.  Since it's a fan, then by setting the center vertex to one of {0.0, 1.0} and applying an alpha test @0.0, I can effectively block the entire object or pass it (fragment alpha > 0.0 if center is >0.0, and ==0.0 otherwise).  Inefficient as all hell but it works.